# Make a C#.NET dll available in VB6

Tags: c#, .net, dll, reference, vb6

Our applications have a lot of shared functionality. Thats why we've made a DLL that contains all these functions, easy to implement! Now, this DLL is written in c#, as are all of our applications. Except for one of them, which is written in VB6.

Referencing a c# dll in VB6 does not work. This application is the base of all our other applications, so rewriting it in c# is not an option here. Any clue as to how to make this dll accessible through both c# projects, as well as VB6 projects?

Answer (score 2):

If you expose your C# dll as a COM component, it will be available for use in VB6 too. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3511/Exposing-NET-Components-to-COM) is an article that tells how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

@danish's answer of COM is the answer if you want to use DLL linking/references.

But for completeness an alternative might be that the C# side exposes Web Services, which can be consumed by the VB6 app.  [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730836%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) MSDN article shows a VB6 app using WebServices.  This has a benefit that when the VB6 side is upgraded the existing C# WebService shouldn't need changes, and your not reliant the depreciated COM technology.